# Evaluation Homomorphism How $ker\phi={0}$ then $\phi$ is injective,, How proof that $\phi$ is surjective??

Tags: ring-theory

help with this excercises, I am trying proof a theorem.

The thorem is: Get $E$ be extension of $F$ and get $a\in E$ if $a$ is transcendental over $F$ Then $F[a]$ isomorphic to $F(a)$

Evaluation Homomorphism

Let $E$ be the extension of $F$ and let $a\in E$

Get:
$$\phi:F[x]  \longrightarrow F(a) $$
if $a$ is transcendental then ker$\phi={0}$ then $\phi$ is 
Injective and surjective, so $$F[a] \cong F(a)$$

How $ker\phi={0}$ then $\phi$ is injective,, How proof that $\phi$ is surjective (onto)??

Comment: It's false. If $a$ is trascendental over $F$, then the map $F[x]\to F(a)$ given by $p(x)\mapsto p(a)$ is never surjective. For instance, it does not contain the inverse of $a$.

Comment: The thorem is: Get $E$ be extension of $F$ and get $a\in E$ if $a$ is transcendental over $F$ Then $F[a]$ isomorphic to $F(a)$

Comment: This so-called theorem is the *opposite* of the truth.

Comment: In fact, there is this theorem: let $F$ be a field, $E$ be an extension of $F$ and $a\in E$. Then, $a$ is *algebraic* over $E$ *if and only if* $F(a)\cong F[a]$.